# creating a NSURLRequest causing iPhone app to crash

Tags: iphone, url, nsurlrequest

My iPhone app crashes when I try to create an NSURLRequest object. However, I know the url object I'm using is correct. Code and console log are both below. Any advice?

```
NSURL *url = selectedObject.url;
NSLog(url);
NSURLRequest *tempURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
NSLog(@"got here");
```

And console log:

```
2010-11-07 20:41:46.465 DePauw[17643:207] CALayer position contains NaN: [605712 nan]
2010-11-07 20:41:47.988 DePauw[17643:207] CALayer position contains NaN: [59100 nan]
2010-11-07 20:41:49.389 DePauw[17643:207] CALayer position contains NaN: [4405 nan]
2010-11-07 20:41:50.828 DePauw[17643:207] CALayer position contains NaN: [482 nan]
2010-11-07 20:41:54.243 DePauw[17643:207] http://www.depauw.edu/m/
```

As you can see, it prints the NSLog(url) (www.depauw.edu/m/) so I know my url is what I intend it to be. However, it doesn't print the NSLog(@"got here). Even though the program crashes at the NSURLRequest line, the console doesn't generate any crash report or any error, which is what is confusing me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try NSURLRequest *tempURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.depauw.edu/m/"]];

Comment: Seems obvious, but are you certain your selectedObject.url is returning an NSURL and not an NSString?

Comment: to the first comment: The URL is part of a custom annotation object. I have about 100 annotations on my map, and when I finally update my XML file, each URL is going to be unique. So I can't hardcore the URL, I have to access the property of my DPUAnnotation objects.

Comment: to the second comment: I will try a URLWithString: url, but like I said above, the annotations I am using each have a NSURL *url property.